# how to add multiple search data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

so I need help with my code. My boss wanted to search in my dropdown category multiple times for example in ID, more likely a range value, example i want to search SCP ID values: 123 and 169, all significant data will show that matches the record.i attach my UI sample below[sample UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtW87.png) my problem is that in my UI i can only search 1 value only for the same category. someone help me pls with the function and design.  thanks alot.

This is my HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="txtsid" style="width: 70%; margin-left:2px;" value="" ng-model="sid" class="input-group inline form-control" placeholder="SCP ID"  ng-required="true" required>
<button id="scpid1" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addFields()">ADD</button>
```

This is my function:

```
$scope.sid=$scope.sidData;

$scope.filterSearch2nd = function(sid) {
    
    if(sid ==""){
        sid="scpid";
    }
    
    $rootScope.loader = true;
    skinCareProdService.filter2ndSearch(sid)
        .then(function(data){
            $scope.rawSCP = data.data;
            $rootScope.loader = false;
                $scope.sidData=data.data[0].SCP_id;
        }
    );
}
```

i also use append

Comment: i did it with dataTable please i prefer to used [like that](https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html)

Comment: i know that it is not angular, i may hear some suggestions, as i tag it

Comment: thank you @jaykumar , ill check it

Comment: Roger! Ma'am. if you cant find then please share your whole code